# Workflow no regresa los correos

Tags: oracle

Estoy realizando un workflow en Netsuite que gestiona una campaña de publicidad, en particular es el ejemplo de "Wolfe Electronics" que viene en la documentación, pero al momento de ponerlo a prueba no me regresa los correos para poder avanzar.
En general el workflow envía un correo (state1), si el correo que llega se le da clic al enlace contenido avanza al state 1a y espera 1 día para mandar otro correo, si no, pasa al state 4 y regresa otro correo y se termina el workflow. Después de pasado 1 día pasa al state2, una vez ahí la transición al estado 2a compara si se le ha dado clic al enlace en el correo, si es así pasa al estado 2a y espera 3 días, si no es así, pasa al state 5 y regresa un correo y se termina el Workflow. Una vez hayan pasado los 3 días pasa al state 3 y regresa un correo.
Ya probé el workflow sin condiciones y sin tiempos de espera entre estados y si me regresa los correos, pero no sé porqué al agregarle las condiciones (comparar si se le dió click al enlace en el correo) o los tiempos de espera en las transiciones no me regresa nada.
Cabe destacar que las acciones se hacen mediante un Workflow Action existente ya en Netsuite, el "Send email campaing".
Agradecería cualquier consejo u opinión :)
[image: Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única solución encontrada fue agregar una acción de tipo "Send email" antes que la de tipo "Send Email Campaing", desconozco aún porqué pasa esto, pero hacerlo me ayudó a ejecutar el workflow como quería.